# TextFormField with Date Picker - readOnly with validator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with a **TextFormField** for a date picker. I have it set to readOnly so that there won't be a cursor or keyboard when picking the date in the field.

But I also want to have the **validator** show a *red error message* if no date is picked (Cancel button is pushed), the validator doesn't work when **readOnly** is set to true.

How can I achieve all this together, in a simple manner?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71647499/13997210) hope its help to you.

Comment: Hey, I already have achieved what you have written there, it's easy with just the readOnly property, no keyboard or cursor ever pops up when you have it set to true, no need any more code. But after that my issue is using the validator, it is a property that gives an error message if you have not written a valid input into the field.